# How symfony parse and use annotation

Tags: php, symfony, parsing, annotations, symfony4

Using Symfony annotation for example for routing is quite amazing, but I wonder how this framework parse the comments and extract the annotation?
For example:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/tehran", name="tehran")
 */
```

and then use it as a route to next controller method.

Comment: I think you should have to read this https://www.sitepoint.com/your-own-custom-annotations/.

Comment: Well, its a guide to make customized annotation in symfony. But regardless of Symfony services how this work.

Answer (score 5):

Symfony uses the Doctrine Annotations module to parse the docblock from your class.

See:

https://github.com/doctrine/annotations

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/current/index.html

It uses Reflection class to read the annotations

https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/book.reflection.php

Symfony will read from your annotations on the first run (and will cache the parsed routes).
Then the routes are matched with the current request using an UrlMatcher.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php