# How to create custom annotation in PHP?

Tags: php, annotations

I would like to learn how to use and create custom annotations for my projects. I don't want to use a framework. However, I am open to using a library for that.

Any guidelines? Any examples of how to do it?

For example, lets say I want to create custom ORM:

```
/*
 *@Table(name="TableName")
 */
class TableName{
    /*
    *@Column(type="int")
    */
    protected $id;

    public static createTabe(){/*creates table with properties defined in the annotation*/}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your use-case? Give some examples of what you're wanting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How symfony parse and use annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52090295/how-symfony-parse-and-use-annotation)

Comment: @PatrickQ I just want to learn how to do it. Let's say I want to create custom ORM.

Comment: @dodo254  I suggest you start by having a read of [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html).  The best way to learn is going to be to see how it is already being done.  As it stands, this is too-broad to be addressed here.